# I want to post from my site on my fanpage

Tags: facebook-graph-api, fan-page

I have create an app in facebook and, between php sdk, i can post the article of my site on my profile.

Now, i want to post my article in my fanpage and not in my prfile. how i can do this?

This is the code that i use, not much different from the example in facebook developers:

```
    // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
  // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
  require_once('facebook.php');


  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();


?>


  <?
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();  
        $page_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';   
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'link' => $link,
                                      'message' => $titolo,
                                      'picture' => 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                                      'name' => 'Ecosport',
                                      'access_token' => $access_token
                                 ));
        echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                       'scope' => 'publish_stream'

                       )); 

        header("location:$login_url");             


        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
      // Give the user a logout link 

      $id_articolo=$_GET['id_articolo'];

      header("location:xxxxxxxxxx");

      /*echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';*/
    } else {

      // No user, so print a link for the user to login
      // To post to a user's wall, we need publish_stream permission
      // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
      // need to specify it here.
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );

      header("location:$login_url");

      /*echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';*/

    } 

  ?>
```

Oviusly the "xxxx" are used for privacy. I tied to change this " $facebook->api('/me/feed',...... " into this " $facebook->api('/$page_id/feed',....... " but nothing. I can't to post my article in my fanpage.

Can you help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for the `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` permissions.  Then call to /me/accounts to get a list of accounts (aka pages) that the user administers.  Each account in that list of accounts will have an access token associated with it.  That access token is special and will need to be used to new up an instance of the facebook api.  Once you do that, posting to the page wall is the same as posting to a user's wall (i.e. /me/feed)

Comment: See the Page Login section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: DMCS, that posts to the fan page as the user. Do you know how to make it post to the fan page *as the fan page?*

Comment: No, my above explanation does not post to the stream as a user, it posts as a page because it uses the PAGE's access token.